# perl operator s///e not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl, syntax

I'm trying to figure out why this is working :

```
 $_='12+34';$x=1;
 s/(\d+)(.)(\d+)/"\$x$2$2"/ee; # This is working, does $x++

 print "x=$x \n";              # x=2
```

while this is not :

```
 $_='12+34';$x=1;
 s/(\d+)(.)(\d+)/\$x$2$2/e; # This is NOT working 

 # Error message is :
 # Scalar found where operator expected at ./test.pl line 2, near "$x$2"
 #        (Missing operator before $2?)
```

I have the guts that `s/xxx/yyy/e` and `s/xxx/"yyy"/ee` should behave the same, but obviously I'm wrong.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the *expression* modifier -- a single `/e`

It causes the *replacement* string to be treated as a Perl expression, and is essentially an alternative to the standard mode, which is to process the string as if it were in double-quotes

Normally

```
my $x = 1;
my $y = '12+34';

$y =~ s/(\d+)(.)(\d+)/\$x$2$2/;
```

produces a replacement equivalent to the string `qq{\$x$2$2}`, which is `$x++`

If you add an `/e` then the replacement is treated as a Perl expression, and you are getting errors because `\$x$2$2` isn't valid Perl. You could get the same result as before by using

```
s/(\d+)(.)(\d+)/'$x' . $2 . $2/e
```

or, as you have seen, the string expression

```
s/(\d+)(.)(\d+)/"\$x$2$2"/e
```

But all these do is evaluate the Perl expression. There is no way to execute arbitrary Perl code that is constructed from parts of the target string without adding a second `/e` modifier which stands for *eval*

The resulting `/ee` causes Perl to treat the replacement as an *expression* (instead of doing double-quote interpolation on it) and then *eval* the result of that expression

For instance

```
s/(\d+)(.)(\d+)/'$x' . $2 . $2/ee
```

first evaluates the expression `'$x' . $2 . $2` giving `$x++` and then does `eval` on that string, returning 1 (so the original `12+34` is replaced with `1`) and incrementing `$x`

You can use *expression* mode with a single `/e` if you can write a Perl expression that does what you need. Otherwise you need to use `/ee` to get an *eval* stage as well

I think it's clearer to use braces if you involve `/e` at all. That way it looks like Perl code and not a string replacement

```
s{(\d+)(.)(\d+)}{
    '$x' . $2 . $2
}ee
```

Comment: Correcto!! `/ee` double evaluates the RHS

Comment: @Gerry: *Wrong!* I went to great lengths to explain that the first `/e` treats the replacement as an *expression*. It doesn't `eval` anything. A second `/e` will `eval` the value of the expression

Comment: Perfect answer. It's now clearer. I missed the fact that the replacement part was embedded in an invisible qq{...} which is NOT present when using ///e modifier. Thanks.

Comment: @Orabîg: Exactly. `s/pattern/replacement/` is identical to `s/pattern/qq{replacement}/e`

Comment: I say you are correct then you say I am wrong by saying that? `e` evaluates the right side as an expression. `ee` evaluates the right side as a string then evaluate the result. That seems like double evaluation to me.

Comment: @Gerry: If you're going to use "evaluates" so broadly then the replacement is also evaluated without any `/e` at all. So in your terms, there is no difference between `/e` and no `/e` -- both evaluate the replacement once.